# Is there a way to use Scipy Peak Detection using the 'left side' of the peak?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to perform negative peak (trough or local minima) detection in python. I'll call it a neg peak. However, I'd like to favor the left side of the neg peak. This will help as new real-time data comes in. I like scipy and the 'prominence' parameter. however, as far as I can tell the prominence weights left and right sides of the neg peak equally.

I have a dataframe, df, with a column RSI_MA14. I'd like to label this last neg peak (the one around x=200). Is there a way to give weight to the L side using the prominence argument in scipy, or maybe a similar library or strategy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as signal

# Find the local minima using find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(-df['RSI_MA14'], prominence = 10)
local_minima = df.iloc[peaks]

# Plot the line graph
plt.plot(df.index, df['RSI_MA14'])

# add the peaks
for i in peaks:
plt.scatter(i, df['RSI_MA14'][i], color='red')
```

[image]